# IServiceCollection extension method not working

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement DI using extension methods in .net. Here is the source code

***src/Application/DependencyInjection.cs***

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Application;

public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services) {
        var assembly = typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly;

        services.AddMediatR(configuration =>
            configuration.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly)
        );
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(assembly);
        return services;
            
    }
}
```

***src/WebApi/Program.cs***

```
builder.Services.AddApplication(); // this throws an error (method not found)
```

this is the error I get:

*'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddApplication' and no accessible extension method 'AddApplication' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found*

Comment: And do you get any errors? Or are you just missing registrations?

Comment: @Flidor I get this error when compiling: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddApplication' and no accessible extension method 'AddApplication' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found

Comment: I would guess, you are missing the appropriate `using` for your `Application` namespace?

Comment: What happens if you put the cursor on AddApplication() and hit Ctrl+. ? VS should suggest to add that using for you.

Comment: @Fildor it offers code formatting, no usings :(

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I added using Application, it solved the problem! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

"using Application" in Program.cs was missing